# Flutter gives Unexpected character: Undefined location error while working with graphql

Tags: flutter, graphql

I have setup my graphql client with library `graphql_flutter` and I am trying to make a call from another page to render list of items from the server API as follows:

Graphql client setup at `main.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


   // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(uri: 'http://192.168.122.1:8000/graphql');

    final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink();
    final Link link = httpLink as Link;

    ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
      GraphQLClient(
        cache: NormalizedInMemoryCache(
            dataIdFromObject: _typenameDataIdFromObject),
        link: link,
      ),
    );



    return GraphQLProvider(
        client: client,
        child: CacheProvider(
            child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter graphql',
                theme: ThemeData(
                  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                ),
                home: CategoriesPage())));
  }

    String _typenameDataIdFromObject(Object object) {
    if (object is Map<String, Object> &&
        object.containsKey('__typename') &&
        object.containsKey('id')) {
      return "${object['__typename']}/${object['id']}";
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I have set up `Django server` in order to fetch the data as in the image. The API is rendering the items as intended.

[image]

And, on my other page, I have the 'query` to fetch the data.

```
String projectsQuery = r"""
query {
    projects {
      id
      title
      __typename
    }
}
""";

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


return Query(
    options: QueryOptions(document: projectsQuery),
    builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch}) {
      Widget body = _apiResult(result);

      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Categories'), actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                tooltip: 'Login',
                onPressed: () {}),
          ]),
          body: body);
    });
}

  Widget _apiResult(QueryResult result) {

   print(result.errors)
   if (result.errors != null) {
   return Text('Error');
  }
  if (result.loading) {
   return Text('Loading...');
  }
    return CategoriesList(categories: result.data['data']['projects']);
}}
```

I have printed the `result.errors` in above function `_apiResult`. It is giving the following errors: `[Unexpected character: Undefined location]`

And, at the end of flutter console following message is being displayed:

```
I/flutter (26761): [FormatException, FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (26761): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (26761): ^
I/flutter (26761): ]
```

```
I/flutter ( 3666): http://192.168.122.1:8000/graphql/
I/flutter ( 3666): request body :
I/flutter ( 3666): {operationName: UNNAMED/229217349, variables: {}, query:     query {
I/flutter ( 3666):         projects {
I/flutter ( 3666):           id
I/flutter ( 3666):           title
I/flutter ( 3666):           __typename
I/flutter ( 3666):         }
I/flutter ( 3666):     }
I/flutter ( 3666):     }
```

And, the current error is:

```
 {"errors":[{"message":"Unknown operation named \"UNNAMED/229217349\"."}]}
```

I have not checked this before, but find out Django is also raising error

```
Bad Request: /graphql/
[30/Apr/2019 13:01:38] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 400 73
```

So, I think the issue is at Django, not able to get the request in the right format. My API request seems wrong.

Comment: is there more log? To me error seems like the server is returning HTML page. How have you setup GraphQL server?

Comment: Hi @Ryosuke, I have updated my question above. Yes, I have setup 'django for GraphQL'.

Comment: this package seems to have changed a lot since I tried it last. Try this: open the `link_http.dart` file. You can do this by cmd/ctrl + left_click on the import statement in Android Studio or Intellij IDEA. Then add the line after line 297 : `print(decodedBody);`

Comment: this would let us know what is the response. Also my code was like this  `ValueNotifier(
    Client(
        endPoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:4000',
        cache: InMemoryCache(),
        apiToken: '$token'
    ),
  );` so maybe you don't need to add `/graphql/` at the end of your url.

Comment: @Ryosuke , I found that the my django url is setup with '/graphql/', so it is working with the url now but raising different error. I have updated my error above.

Comment: try changing your query to : `query $queryName {
    projects {
      id
      title
      __typename
    }
}` where queryName is the same as something defined in your GraphQL schema.

Answer (score 2):

I had an error which was very similar to this one

```
[Unknown operation named "UNNAMED/355583712".: Undefined location]
```

I solved it by adding a name to the query like so:

```
query NameOfQuery {
  projects {
    id
    title
    __typename
  }
}
```